# Get UIDatePicker variable from another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm sure I have something dumb wrong, but I'm trying to pass the data set in a UIDatePicker from one view to another (I'm using the Utility Template in Xcode).

I've written out all of the pertinent code below.

---

FlipsideViewController.h

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
```

---

FlipsideViewController.m

```
@synthesize datePicker;
```

---

mainViewController.m

```
NSDate *time = flipsideViewController.datePicker.date;
```

---

Logging time returns null.

Also, I'm positive I've properly linked datePicker to the UIDatePicker element in Interface Builder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flipsideViewController.datePicker.date` may not exist by the time you go back to `mainViewController`. You need to set it before you release or return from the `FlipViewController` view.